# How to handle non json format response in volley

Tags: android

I am getting a response from the server that is not in JSON format, i just got "nullnull" as response. In this case how can i handle the response because it is not in json format. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: make `StringRequest`.

Comment: Fix the server code to always return JSON

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, keep error  JSON for error cases and return that JSON.

---

**Another way**

You can make string request and handle the response.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(method, YOUR_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                     //.... handle your response   
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      //.. handle error                          
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

could be sensible to catch the Exception raised while trying to get the json object.

```
String httpResponse = "put your http response string"
try {
      JSONObject ResponseObject = new JSONObject(httpResponse);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // if (httpResponse == "nullnull") ...
    }
```